# React big calendar, add bootstrap popover to event?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

Looks like you can create custom components for the react calendar component. I was looking at this example:

https://github.com/intljusticemission/react-big-calendar/blob/master/examples/demos/customView.js.

But it isn't clear how to create a custom event component. I'm also looked through the documentation, but there are no explicit examples:

http://intljusticemission.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html#prop-components

I'm particularly interested in creating a tooltip for each event that shows a more detailed event description.

Can anyone point to an example of where someone has created a custom component for react-big-calendar?

UPDATE:
Here is an image of the calendar and some events rendered in the month view. I'm thinking, a custom event should definitely include the 'rbc-event' and 'rbc-event-content'. To add the bootstrap tool tip I'm thinking something like this in the custom event component:

[image]

And here is where the event cell component is created in the react-big-calendar source code.

```
    return _react2.default.createElement(
              'div',
              _extends({}, props, {
                style: _extends({}, props.style, style),
                className: (0, _classnames2.default)('rbc-event', className, xClassName, {
                  'rbc-selected': selected,
                  'rbc-event-allday': isAllDay || _dates2.default.diff(start, _dates2.default.ceil(end, 'day'), 'day') > 1,
                  'rbc-event-continues-prior': continuesPrior,
                  'rbc-event-continues-after': continuesAfter
                }),
                onClick: function onClick() {
                  return onSelect(event);
                }
              }),
              _react2.default.createElement(
                'div',
                { className: 'rbc-event-content', title: title },
                Component ? _react2.default.createElement(Component, { event: event, title: title }) : title
              )
    );
  }
});

exports.default = EventCell;
module.exports = exports['default'];
```

I decided to try extending the EventCell component, when I passed it in as the event component prop, the event no longer had any content. Not sure how to pass event details into the 'rcb-event' div inside of the EventCell component. See below..

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import MyCalendar from '../components/bigCalendar';
import _ from 'lodash';
import EventCell from 'react-big-calendar/lib/EventCell.js';

class MyEvent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="testing">
                <EventCell />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

let components = {
    event: MyEvent
}
```

Here, I am passing the components object I just created down to the MyCalendar presentation component:

```
export default class Calendar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        var eventsList = Object.keys(props).map(function(k){
            return props[k];
        });

        eventsList.map(function(event){
            event["start"] = new Date(event["start"])
            event["end"] = new Date(event["end"])
        })

        this.state = {
            events: eventsList
        };
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <MyCalendar components={components} events={this.state.events}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And, finally passing the components object to the presentation component via props. Which does successfully render in the view, but as I said earlier - without content.

```
const MyCalendar = props => (
    <div className="calendar-container">
        <BigCalendar
            selectable
            popup
            components={props.components}
            views={{month: true, week: true, day: true}}
            events={props.events}
            onSelectEvent={event => onSelectEvent(event)}
            eventPropGetter={eventStyleGetter}
            scrollToTime={new Date(1970, 1, 1, 6)}
            defaultView='month'
            defaultDate={new Date(2015, 3, 12)}
            />
    </div>
);

MyCalendar.propTypes = {
    events: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    components: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```

Seems like I'm supposed to go about this another way...Any suggestions?

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Added some things I've tried - would be great if you could take a look

Comment: "Can anyone point to an example of where someone has created a custom component for react-big-calendar?" makes the question off-topic (requesting pointers to off-site resources is specifically off-topic: [help/on-topic]). It would be good to remove it.  In general, it is preferable to include information (code, errors, etc.) in the question in text format as opposed to images. An image is better than nothing, but text lets it be copied or searched. An image might be a good idea (even in addition to text) if it provides additional information. Basically: text >>> image >>>>>>>> nothing.

Comment: I added a bunch of code with notes, did you not see this?

Comment: I did. Adding that code is a very significant improvement to the question, which will be helpful to someone answering. However, you also added an image of code in the "react-big-calendar source code" which could have been copy&pasted. That would be better. Don't just remove the image: add the code as text, a pointer to the code online, and then remove the image. In addition, the request for an external resource is still in the question (if that is removed, I would retract my close vote and delete the comment about it being off-topic). I'm just providing suggestions for improving the question.

Comment: will do, understood

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I came up with, I'm sure it could be cleaned up - but it works.

Create custom Event component, which includes the popover content.

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import MyCalendar from '../components/bigCalendar';
import _ from 'lodash';

class MyEvent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        MyGlobal.popOver();
    }
    render(){
        return (
        <div>
            <div    className="custom_event_content"
                    data-toggle="popover"
                    data-placement="top"
                    data-popover-content={"#custom_event_" + this.props.event.id}
                    tabIndex="0"
                    >
                {this.props.event.title}
            </div>

            <div className="hidden" id={"custom_event_" + this.props.event.id} >
              <div className="popover-heading">
                {this.props.event.driver}
              </div>

              <div className="popover-body">
                {this.props.event.title}<br/>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        );
    }
}

let components = {
    event: MyEvent
}

export default class Calendar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        var eventsList = Object.keys(props).map(function(k){
            return props[k];
        });

        eventsList.map(function(event){
            event["start"] = new Date(event["start"])
            event["end"] = new Date(event["end"])
        })

        this.state = {
            events: eventsList
        };
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <MyCalendar components={components} events={this.state.events}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Add event listeners:

```
MyGlobal.popOver = function(){
    $('body').on('click', function (e) {
        //did not click a popover toggle or popover
        if ($(e.target).data('toggle') !== 'popover'
            && $(e.target).parents('.popover.in').length === 0) {
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('hide');
        }
    });

    $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
        html : true,
        container: 'body',
        content: function() {
            var content = $(this).attr("data-popover-content");
            return $(content).children(".popover-body").html();
        },
        title: function() {
            var title = $(this).attr("data-popover-content");
            return $(title).children(".popover-heading").html();
        }
    });
}
```

Pass custom props to MyCalendar presentation component:

```
const MyCalendar = props => (
    <div className="calendar-container">
        <BigCalendar
            selectable
            popup
            components={props.components}
            views={{month: true, week: true, day: true}}
            events={props.events}
            onSelectEvent={event => onSelectEvent(event)}
            eventPropGetter={eventStyleGetter}
            scrollToTime={new Date(1970, 1, 1, 6)}
            defaultView='month'
            defaultDate={new Date(2015, 3, 12)}
            />
    </div>
);

MyCalendar.propTypes = {
    events: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    components: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```

Comment: Interesting solution, just curious where does MyGlobal.popOver go? In normal JS file?

Answer (score 2):

Just to update answer to **2020** using **moment** and **reactstrap**.

```
import React, {FC} from "react";
import {Calendar, Event, momentLocalizer, ToolbarProps} from "react-big-calendar";
import {UncontrolledTooltip} from "reactstrap";
import moment from "moment";

const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment);

interface CalendarToolbarProps extends ToolbarProps {

}

const CalendarToolbar: FC<CalendarToolbarProps> = ({date, view: viewMode, onView, ...props}) => {
    return <div>Whatever you want on toolbar</div>
};


const eventPropGetter = (event: any, start: any, end: any, isSelected: boolean) => {
    const style = {
        backgroundColor: "#FF0000",
        paddingLeft: "10px",
        color: 'white',
    };
    return {
        style: style
    };
}

export interface FooEvent extends Event {
}

interface CalendarWithTooltipProps {
    events: Event[]
}

const CalendarWithTooltip: FC<CalendarWithTooltipProps> = ({events, ...props}) => {
    return <Calendar
        events={events}
        localizer={localizer}
        eventPropGetter={eventPropGetter}
        className={"overflow-scroll"}
        components={{
            event: (component: any) => {
                const targetId = "...."
                const {event} = component
                return <div id={targetId}>
                    {event?.title}
                    <UncontrolledTooltip placement={"top"}
                                         autohide={false}
                                         style={{minWidth: 200}}
                                         target={targetId} trigger={"hover"}>
                        Your tooltip content
                    </UncontrolledTooltip>
                </div>
            },
            toolbar: (props) => <CalendarToolbar {...props}/>
        }}
    />
}

export default CalendarWithTooltip
```

Comment: How we can show the selected event in the tooltip ? currently it is showing all the events.

Comment: Could you please help me out ?